# Relabel levels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas DataFrame I'm trying to relabel the two levels of a variable with one single name but leave the 'Nan' values in the variable untouched.

Below is a reproducible example using a modified version of the 'mtcars' dataset. Here I want to relabel the 'yes' and 'no' levels of the 'am' variable to 'new' for example.

```
                    mpg   cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs  am  
Mazda RX4           21.0  six 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  yes     
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  two 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  NaN    
Datsun 710          22.8  six 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  no    
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  two 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  NaN   
Hornet Sportabout   18.7  six 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  yes  
Valiant             18.1  two 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  NaN   
Duster 360          14.3  two 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  no
```

Result would look like this:

```
                    mpg   cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs  am  
Mazda RX4           21.0  six 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  new     
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  two 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  NaN    
Datsun 710          22.8  six 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  new    
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  two 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  NaN   
Hornet Sportabout   18.7  six 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  new  
Valiant             18.1  two 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  NaN   
Duster 360          14.3  two 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  mt['am'] = mt.am.map(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else 'new')
```

Output:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(['yes',np.nan,'no',np.nan], columns=['am'])

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
    am
0  yes
1  NaN
2   no
3  NaN

In [23]: df['am'] = df.am.map(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else 'new')

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
    am
0  new
1  NaN
2  new
3  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 methods here, first is the assumption that non-`NaN` values should be set to 'new' using [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html#pandas.Series.notnull):

```
In [21]:
df.loc[df['am'].notnull(),'am'] = 'new'
df

Out[21]:
                    mpg  cyl  disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs   am
Mazda RX4          21.0  six   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46   0  new
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0  two   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02   0  NaN
Datsun 710         22.8  six   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61   1  new
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4  two   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44   1  NaN
Hornet Sportabout  18.7  six   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02   0  new
Valiant            18.1  two   225  105  2.76  3.460  20.22   1  NaN
Duster 360         14.3  two   360  245  3.21  3.570  15.84   0  new
```

The other is to filter just those rows that have 'yes' or 'no' to be set to 'new' using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
In [23]:
df.loc[df['am'].isin(['yes','no']),'am'] = 'new'
df

Out[23]:
                    mpg  cyl  disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs   am
Mazda RX4          21.0  six   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46   0  new
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0  two   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02   0  NaN
Datsun 710         22.8  six   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61   1  new
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4  two   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44   1  NaN
Hornet Sportabout  18.7  six   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02   0  new
Valiant            18.1  two   225  105  2.76  3.460  20.22   1  NaN
Duster 360         14.3  two   360  245  3.21  3.570  15.84   0  new
```

Comment: Both answers are great. I used bleh's first.

Comment: @EdChum, +1 for the more elegant `.loc` solution